# Online Interactive Consoles

Tags: compiler-construction, interpreter

Where can I find an online interactive console for programming language or api?

- [Ruby](http://tryruby.org/)
- [Python](http://shell.appspot.com/)
- [Groovy](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/)
- PHP?
- Perl?
- [Scheme](http://eval.ironscheme.net/)
- [Java](http://www.javarepl.com/)
- C?

Comment: There is a nice list of such tools by [Joel Franusic](http://joel.franusic.com/w/page/26128430/Online-REPs-and-REPLs)

Comment: @kuszi thanks for the link. Your post is definitely the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@kuszi Put a great answer as a comment to the question, but I almost missed it because it was a comment rather than the answer.

[This link](http://joel.franusic.com/w/page/26128430/Online-REPs-and-REPLs) goes to a huuuge list of REPs and REPLs for tons of languages.

Answer (score 7):

- [Ruby](http://tryruby.hobix.com/)
- [Python](http://try-python.mired.org/)

Comment: That online Python interpreter is basically worthless for learning Python.  You can't define your own functions or classes, so it's not going to be much use to anyone.

Comment: dead links -- see repl.it instead

Answer (score 7):

[repl.it](http://repl.it/) supports multiple languages including Python, Ruby, Lua, Scheme, CoffeeScript, QBasic, Forth,...the list goes on.

Comment: That Ruby interpreter is off for some reason. `a = Time.new` produces an error. It does say Beta on the link, but wow.

Answer (score 5):

Google has an [online interactive shell for Python](http://shell.appspot.com/).

Comment: this shell has some major bugs. I couldn't manipulate an object property inside an object method

Answer (score 5):

[Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/) is a Python implementation in JavaScript.  Pretty cool.

Answer (score 3):

[_Why](http://whytheluckystiff.net/) made one for [Ruby](http://tryruby.hobix.com/)

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted here?  marxidad just duplicated this information

Answer (score 3):

http://www.codepad.org/? It has support for a few languages, including perl, scheme, c/c++, python, lua and more.

Answer (score 2):

For Java you could try http://www.javarepl.com (or console version at https://github.com/albertlatacz/java-repl)

Answer (score 1):

You can play around with [jsScheme](http://www.bluishcoder.co.nz/jsscheme/) for Scheme, but it's a toy and shouldn't replace a console-based interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome Python shell https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gdiimmpmdoofmahingpgabiikimjgcia

Answer (score 1):

You can try this http://doc.pyschools.com/console.
It is actually an editor, and is good for testing your python code online when you do not have it installed on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

[python web console](http://pythonwebconsole.thomnichols.org/), and I was able to run the code below

```
# Script text here
import itertools

g = itertools.chain("AB", range(2))

print g.next()
print g.next()
print g.next()
print g.next()
```

Answer (score 1):

http://repl.it/ is a Python in a browser without Java or Silverlight (as well as dozen of other languages compiled to JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

[Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite) for Javascript. And, [Rainbow 9](http://vimeo.com/10499321) was one of the first examples of online REPLs.

Answer (score 0):

http://lotrepls.appspot.com/ is a console that works reasonably well for all these scripting languages:

- python
- ruby
- groovy
- beanshell
- clojure
- javascript
- scala
- scheme

Just hit CTRL+SPACE to switch languages or use the metacommand '/switch', for example '/switch clojure' to start coding in clojure.